# How to remove the auto generated total column from paginated reports in power bi report builder

Tags: reporting-services, dax, ssrs-tablix, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am trying to develop a matrix chart in Power BI report builder (paginated report). When I drop the data field, it auto-generates the total column like this which  are highlighted yellow

[image]

The property of the paginated reports are like this

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to remove the yellow highlighted auto-generated column from he report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is a total column, otherwise it would show in the report design.

It looks like your data may contain rows with blank years/months and/or blank portfolio/account names so the matrix is simply aggregating those as it would with any other data.

I suggest you look at the output of your dataset query and filter the data out there or if that is not possible for whatever reason. Filter the data out in the dataset filter properties.

Comment: It is exactly like you mentioned, it was a blank row and not total

Comment: Now I hvae a second issue. I want to actually a total but this this sum is the total of values in individual rows instead of a simple sum. Can you please tell me how do I achieve to total up the values in all rows. Please remember that in my case, total sum (debit amount) is different than summing up the debit amount in each row

Comment: You need to create a new question for this. Make sure you include your report design again and show sample data and expected results so it's clear to people exactly what you are after and where in the report is must sit. The location of aggregations (the row and column groups etc.) is important as it will affect the expression used.